# Redirect to index in subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file inside `root/en`, when you enter the URL `root/en` I want the site to redirect to `root/en/public/index.php` and find the index there. I have this solution but for some reason it doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /en

ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !en/public/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ en/public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using that as front controller then use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /en/

RewriteRule ^$ public/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).+)$ public/index.php/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: yes I am using that index as front controller, If I use your solution my browser only displays the content of the `root/en` folder

Comment: Yes this is the only .htaccess file in my `/en/` with only the above code and no my `en/public` contains no other .htaccess files

Comment: and I entered `root/en` URL (localhost/en)

Comment: Now I get 404 Page Not Found, my god this is annoying I tryed everything myself... If I type the URL `root/en/public` it works but not if I type `root/en`

Comment: I think the problem is in Codeigniter as I am using that as my framework